# How to know if a SQL query accesses a table using its primary or alternative key?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

For example, this query:

```
SELECT 
    CLIENT, TITLE, SEASON, 
    COUNT('X') N_EPISODIOS 
FROM 
    LIC_SERIES 
GROUP BY 
    CLIENT, TITLE, SEASON;
```

And his table `LIC_SERIES` is:

```
CREATE TABLE lic_series
(
    client VARCHAR2(15), 
    datetime DATE,
    title VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL, 
    season  NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    episode NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_licsS 
        PRIMARY KEY (client, title, season, episode),
    CONSTRAINT 
        FK_licsS1 FOREIGN KEY (title,season) REFERENCES seasons
);
```

I would like to know if there is any command or some way to know if the previous query accesses the table by primary or alternative key, and why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if there is any command or some way to know if the previous query
>   accesses the table by primary or alternative key

Yes, Use [EXPLAIN PLAN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231) for that query. The generated query plan would be able to show you if index have been used and which one and where.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT CLIENT,TITLE,SEASON, COUNT('X') N_EPISODIOS FROM LIC_SERIES 
GROUP BY CLIENT,TITLE,SEASON;
```

View the query plan with a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

Answer (score 2):

Explain plan may sometimes differs from actual execute plan. so if you surmise that query doesn't execute as you expected , you can check actual plan from V$SQL_PLAN_STATISTICS_ALL system view,

```
select *
  from v$sql_plan_statistics_all
 where sql_id = 'your_query_sql_id'
```

`SQL_ID` of the actual executing query can be taken from 
`select * from v$session` find your session and provide the `sql_id` to the first query.

Difference between explain plan and actual plan often occurs when database used awhile, and Oracle can gather statistics of table usage.